# Insert the data into the remote table from # temp table in the stored procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in AZURE SQL database.In that there is a requirement to insert the records  into the remote table from #temp table.
As xxxx_table is in the remote database used sp_execute_remote.

below is the scenario:

```
Create Procedure  SP1 parameter1, Parameter2
As

    select Distinct B.column1, B.Column2
    into #A
    from (Query1
          Union 
          Query2) B

    if (select count(1) from #A) > 0
    Begin

          Exec  sp_execute_remote @data_source_name = N'Remotedatabase',
          @stmt = N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[xxxx_table]
                    SELECT DISTINCT 
                    'xxx' AS 'column1',
                    'xxx as 'Column2',
                    'xxx' AS 'Column3',
                    'xxx' AS 'Column4',
                    'xxx' AS Column4
                    FROM #A A INNER JOIN table1 on A.Column1 = Table1.Column2'

    End 
    )
```

Getting the syntax error as below:

Incorrect syntax near 'xxx'.

Where am i going wrong? or let me know if there is another way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes. Syntax error is showing at the column1 Line. I'm using Azure SQL database

Comment: i didn't get your point - Don't quote the fields 'xxx' and column names .suppose for example for  column1 i have to hardcode the SSIS as Application, Column2 --> ClientName  as ClientName

Comment: you have single quoted with '  field in you select sentence and column names too . use column1 instead of 'column1' and xxx instead of 'xxx'

Comment: Thanks, Net.That worked. While inserting  the data from #temp table into the  remote database table. Error retrieving data from shard [DataSource=xxxxx Database=xxxx].  The underlying error message received was: 'Invalid object name '#A'.'. How to insert the data when tables are on 2 different databases.

Comment: In the same server?

Comment: server.schema.tablename will be ignored as it is referencing to the object in tempdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to dynamically build a string in SQL single-quote the whole sentence, or use 'some text' + 'another text' to concat sentences. If you must add single quote use a double single quote ''

Example:

```
DECLARE @param1 int;
DECLARE @param1 VARCHAR(10);

SET @param1 = 10;
SET @param2 = 'CCDOS87'

@Stmt = 'SELECT Field1 FROM TableName WHERE Field1 = ' 
        + CAST(@param1 AS VARCHAR(100)) 
        + ' AND Field1 = ''' 
        + param2 
        + '''';  <- This is a single '

      @stmt = N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Error_table]
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                xxx AS column1,
                xxx as Column2,
                xxx AS Column3,
                xxx AS Column4,
                xxx AS Environment
                FROM #A A INNER JOIN table1 on A.Column1 = Table1.Column2'
```

**update**

If your tables are in different databases but in the same server use:

```
INSERT INTO SERVER.SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
SELECT Something 
    FROM SERVER.SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
```